# Animation speed is increased when cursor is moving in app window using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, canvas

I am trying to do simple animation in Tkinter, just red box is moving pixel by pixel from one side to another. The problem is that when I move cursor on application window the animation has correct speed (33 ms between frames) but when I stop then animation slows down (to about 46 ms). I am using windows 11, IDE PyCharm and python 3.10.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, height=1000, width=1000, bg='white')
canvas.pack()
box = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 475, 50, 525, fill='red')


def animation():
    global start
    print(str(int((time.time() - start)*1000)) + "ms")
    start = time.time()
    canvas.move(box, 1, 0)
    root.after(33, animation)


start = time.time()
animation()
root.mainloop()
```

After spending some time on searching forums for similar cases I found only one in which the solution was different version of python but I tried and it didn't work. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like perhaps Windows-specific problem. On my mac the animation runs the same whether the cursor is over the window or not.

Comment: Perhaps a Windows 11 - specific problem, since it seems to run the same whether the cursor is on the window (both moving and not moving) or off the window on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I have tried to run it on another computer with windows 10 and it has the same issue.

Comment: timing is handled by the OS scheduler, so it's never going to be that accurate, on my machine this code runs at 39ms per frame regardless of the mouse location or minimizing the window.

Comment: For me it doesn't matter if its 33ms or 39ms, main problem is that the animation frame rate is not constant.

Comment: Be aware that the `after` method of tkinter guarantees your function wont be called earlier than your defined delay in ms. Your problem can be either related to a busy application or a busy underlying operating system or even both. While your application maybe trys to update the specified regions of your application, your window manager may not respond immediately to the call if its busy.